# Can't set RDS while creating Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to create a Elastic Beanstalk environment with node.js platform. When I try to add RDS in EB, console is throwing error and I don't know the reason why. If you have any idea, plz leave a comment, thanks.

```
Configuration validation exception: Invalid option value: '5.6' (Namespace: 'aws:rds:dbinstance', OptionName: 'DBEngineVersion'): Engine Version 5.6 not supported for mysql db
```

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RNCK.png)

Comment: Mysql 5.6 has been depricated this month.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is there any way that I can set rds with aws console? Or should i have to set it manually

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this by running:

```
$ eb config
```

The command is going to open a notepad with your configuration settings. Scroll down to the bottom until you see `aws:rds:dbinstance` add a new setting specifying a newer MySQL version (eg. `8.0`) like so:

```
aws:rds:dbinstance:
  HasCoupledDatabase: 'false'
  DBEngineVersion: '8.0'
```

Save and close the file. Your EB environment is going to update and you're then going to be able to change RDS settings via EB Console.

Comment: This gives me:
ServiceError - Configuration validation exception: RDS DB Engine Version option setting is not allowed to changed

Answer (score 0):

For beginners... you should use "eb cli" to use $eb config

and it worked for me, it is great answer. Thanks #duplxey

Something must gone wrong with elastic beanstalk with my